# Error on Index at Command line Catalog Search

Tags: magento-enterprise, enterprise-1.13, index

We just started getting this error at the command line on index. Is it possible to truncate this table and re-index?

```
Catalog Search Index index process unknown error:
exception 'Enterprise_Index_Model_Action_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '13654292' for key 'PRIMARY'' in html/app/code/core/Enterprise/CatalogSearch/Model/Index/Action/Fulltext/Refresh.php:154
Stack trace:
#0
```

EDIT:
I backed up the database and ran the index on my local using the same code

```
Brents-MacBook-Pro-3:brandshopper-uhc brent$ magerun index:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext 


  Reindex  


Started reindex of: catalogsearch_fulltext
Estimated end: 2014-07-04 19:21:55 UTC
Successfully reindexed catalogsearch_fulltext (Runtime: 1m 18s)
```

No I don't know what to think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up truncating the table and then re-indexing and it works now

```
[html]$ magerun index:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext 


  Reindex  


Started reindex of: catalogsearch_fulltext
Estimated end: 2014-07-04 19:53:52 UTC
Successfully reindexed catalogsearch_fulltext (Runtime: 1m 42s)
[html]$
```